# How to UPDATE in SQLite using a LEFT JOIN to select candidate rows

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I have a table `assoc` containing columns

```
local_id, remote_id, cachedData
```

I can successfully run an SQLITE query that looks like

```
SELECT a1.local_id, a1.remote_id FROM assoc a1 LEFT JOIN ....
```

so that I identify certain rows of the `assoc` table that meet my criteria.

What I would like to do is to set `cachedData` to `null` in those rows.

How can I do this? Sqlite doesn't support UPDATE with joins; you can issue subqueries but I can't figure out how to get the syntax correct; it seems nonintuitive to me.

Comment: What is your primary key for `assoc`?

Comment: It's the (local_id, remote_id) pair

Comment: Crap, I was afraid you'd say that. :) I've [asked this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622453/where-col1-col2-in-sql-subquery-using-composite-primary-key) in anticipation of this being the case. If I get the goods, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: If I can figure out how to ALTER TABLE to add an autoincrementing id, I could use that one instead; I can add an additional column.

Comment: (e.g. the primary key has to remain (local_id, remote_id) but I can add another key for disambiguation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 UPDATE assoc SET cachedData = NULL
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM otherTable 
        WHERE otherTable.Col1 = assoc.Col1 AND otherTable.Col2 = assoc.Col1)
```

Be aware that this is not especially performant.

Comment: your technique worked for me in the short term, I think rowid might be the best thing to use longer term.

Comment: Be careful, ROWID can be reused.  You must rigorously enforce the relation.

Comment: @Larry: "rigorously enforce the relation" -- could you elaborate? If this is used only for a single update statement, is there a chance that it is unsafe to use?

Comment: If rows were to be deleted in the "primary" side of the relation, but the corresponding rows were not deleted on the "foreign" side, then new rows added back to the primary-side you would have orphaned foreign-side rows pointing to the new primary-side records.  But you have an earlier issue, which is how to get the ROWID of the primary-side records into the foreign-side table without the JOINed update syntax.

Comment: So, if the two tables are not going to have new rows added or removed, your technique is safe but simply moves the UPDATE issue one step earlier, to when you need to establish the ROWID link between the tables.

Comment: But it's the same table `assoc` that has the rowid, it's not two tables, so rowid isn't exported to or imported from anywhere else. I'm just joining the `assoc` table to another table to select which rows in the `assoc` table are being updated, and using rowid as a primary key to tell update which rows are updated.

Answer (score 0):

If `assoc` has a single column as the primary key (and assuming that it is `local_id`):

```
UPDATE assoc
SET cachedData=NULL
WHERE local_id IN (
  SELECT local_id FROM assoc a1 LEFT JOIN ...
);
```

Comment: What if it has more than one column as the primary key?

Comment: @JasonS I'm afraid I have no answer as of yet for the composite PK situation. Adding a unique key for disambiguation as you suggest above would be one solution.

Answer (score 0):

Aha, there's already a builtin rowid!

```
UPDATE assoc
SET cachedData=NULL
WHERE rowid IN (
   SELECT rowid FROM assoc a1 LEFT JOIN ...
);
```