# WHERE col1,col2 IN (...) [SQL subquery using composite primary key]

Tags: sql, subquery, composite-primary-key

Given a table `foo` with a composite primary key `(a,b)`, is there a legal syntax for writing a query such as:

```
SELECT ... FROM foo WHERE a,b IN (SELECT ...many tuples of a/b values...);
UPDATE foo SET ... WHERE a,b IN (SELECT ...many tuples of a/b values...);
```

If this is not possible, and you could not modify the schema, how could you perform the equivalent of the above?

*I'm also going to put the terms "compound primary key", "subselect", "sub-select", and "sub-query" here for search hits on these aliases.*

**Edit**: I'm interested in answers for standard SQL as well as those that would work with PostgreSQL and SQLite 3.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
sqlite> create table foo (a,b,c);
sqlite> create table bar (x,y);
sqlite> select * from foo where exists (select 1 from bar where foo.a = bar.x and foo.b = bar.y);
```

Replace the `select 1 from bar` with your `select ... many tuples of a/b values ...`.

Or create a temporary table of your `select ... many tuples of a/b values ...` and use it in place of `bar`..

Answer (score 26):

Your syntax is very close to Standard SQL!

The following is valid FULL SQL-92 (as confirmed by the [Mimer SQL-92 Validator](http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser92/index.tml))

```
SELECT * 
  FROM foo 
  WHERE (a, b) IN (
                   SELECT a, b 
                      FROM bar
                  );
```

Of course, not every SQL product supports full SQL-92 (shame!) If anyone would like to see this syntax supported in Microsoft SQL Server, they can vote for it [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/299231/add-support-for-ansi-standard-row-value-constructors).

A further SQL-92 construct that is more widely supported (e.g. by Microsoft SQL Server and Oracle) is `INTERSECT` e.g.

```
SELECT a, b
  FROM Foo
INTERSECT
SELECT a, b
  FROM Bar;
```

Note that these constructs properly handle the `NULL` value, unlike some of the other suggestions here e.g. those using `EXISTS (<equality predicates>)`, concatenated values, etc.

Comment: This is supported in PostgreSql.  `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE (a,b) IN ((1,2),(3,4))`

Comment: FYI the opposite of `INTERSECT` is `EXCEPT`

Comment: Oracle only supports EXCEPT as of 20c, in 19c there is its compatible equivalent MINUS. Not very portable, but might be useful for some of us. Ostin's solution works with 19c.

Answer (score 12):

You've done one very little mistake.
You have to put a,b in parentheses.

```
SELECT ... FROM foo WHERE (a,b) IN (SELECT f,d FROM ...);
```

That works!

Comment: Works in Oracle 19c, too. Can also use NOT IN to find what exists in foo but not in the other table.

Answer (score 4):

The IN syntax you suggested is not valid SQL.  A solution using EXISTS should work across all reasonably compliant SQL RDBMSes:

```
 UPDATE foo SET x = y WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM bar WHERE bar.c1 = foo.c1 AND bar.c2 = foo.c2)
```

Be aware that this is often not especially performant.

Comment: IN and EXISTS should result in the same plan because they are semantically the same. At least in SQL Server you get the same plan anyway.

Answer (score 3):

```
    SELECT ...
      FROM foo
INNER JOIN (SELECT ...many tuples of a/b values...) AS results
        ON results.a = foo.a
       AND results.b = foo.b
```

That what you are looking for?

Comment: That looks good, except that it won't work in the case of `UPDATE` on SQLite3, which [does not support joins in UPDATE](http://sqlite.org/lang_update.html) queries. I'm trying in part to know if the core multi-key IN is legal (I've just read that it is not in SQLite), but also to help [answer this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622353/how-do-i-do-this-update-in-sqlite/4622371#4622371).

Answer (score 1):

With concatenation, this works with PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT a,b FROM foo WHERE a||b IN (SELECT a||b FROM bar WHERE condition);

UPDATE foo SET x=y WHERE a||b IN (SELECT a||b FROM bar WHERE condition);
```

Comment: This is a bad idea, depending on the values of a and b.  Your concatenation will not always be unique.  You can have one record with a=22 and b=1, another record with a=2 and b=21.  Your concatenation would be 221 for both!
A slightly better concatenation would be a||'-'||b, to avoid this problem.

Another problem is that with the concatenation, the query will be slow because the database can't use it's indexes optimally.

Answer (score 0):

`JOINS` and `INTERSECTS` work fine as a substitute for `IN`, but they're not so obvious as a substitute for `NOT IN`, e.g.: inserting rows from `TableA` into `TableB` where they don't already exist in `TableB` where the `PK` on both tables is a composite.

I am currently using the concatenation method above in SQL Server, but it's not a very elegant solution.

Comment: Suggest you look at `MERGE..USING..WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT...`

Answer (score 0):

If you need a solution that doesn't require the tuples of values already existing in a table, you can concatenate the relevant table values and items in your list and then use the 'IN' command.

In postgres this would look like this:

`SELECT * FROM foo WHERE a || '_' || b in ('Hi_there', 'Me_here', 'Test_test');`

While in SQL I'd imagine it might look something like this:

`SELECT * FROM foo WHERE CONCAT(a, "_", b) in ('Hi_there', 'Me_here', 'Test_test');`

Answer (score 0):

Firebird uses this concatenation formula:

> SELECT a,b FROM foo WHERE a||b IN (SELECT a||b FROM bar WHERE
>   condition);