# Select NOT IN multiple columns

Tags: sql, database, multiple-columns

I need to implement the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   friend 
WHERE  ( friend.id1, friend.id2 ) 
         NOT IN (SELECT id1, 
                        id2 
                 FROM   likes)
```

But `NOT IN` can't be implemented on multiple columns. How do I write this query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WHERE col1,col2 IN (...) \[SQL subquery using composite primary key\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622453/where-col1-col2-in-sql-subquery-using-composite-primary-key)

Comment: Your code is valid Standard Full SQl-92 syntax. You only added the 'sql' tag to your question. If you meant a particular product (e.g. SQL Server) then you should find a specific tag for it (the syntax is not supported on SQL Server, BTW).

Comment: Would this happen to be OpenEdge? Unfortunately Open Edge doesn't implement the full SQL-92 specification and neither `not in` or `not exists` work, only a `left join where = null` strategy will work with OpenEdge.

Answer (score 142):

I'm not sure whether you think about:

```
select * from friend f
where not exists (
    select 1 from likes l where f.id1 = l.id and f.id2 = l.id2
)
```

it works only if id1 is related with id1 and id2 with id2 not both.

Comment: It worked in my case. I just wanted to exclude the rows whose A and B columns existed in a Exclusion table. SQL Server 2016.

Comment: It works with MySQL I used it instead of EXCEPT, because MySQL does not supports EXCEPT syntax

Comment: This won't work in SQL Server if id1 or id2 include NULL values, you'll need to use the coalesce function: `select 1 from likes l where coalesce(f.id1, 0) = coalesce(l.id1, 0) and coalesce(f.id2, 0) = coalesce(l.id2, 0)`

Answer (score 24):

Another mysteriously unknown RDBMS. Your Syntax is perfectly fine in PostgreSQL. Other query styles may perform faster (especially the `NOT EXISTS` variant or a `LEFT JOIN`), but your query is perfectly legit.

Be aware of pitfalls with `NOT IN`, though, when involving any `NULL` values:

- [Find records where join doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251180/find-records-where-join-doesnt-exist/14260510#14260510)

Variant with LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT *
FROM   friend f
LEFT   JOIN likes l USING (id1, id2)
WHERE  l.id1 IS NULL;
```

See @Michał's answer for the `NOT EXISTS` variant.
A more detailed assessment of four basic variants:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

Comment: Removed the simplified EXISTS. It's better to use the standard form.

Answer (score 10):

I use a way that may look stupid but it works for me.
I simply concat the columns I want to compare and use NOT IN:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
WHERE CONCAT(t1.first_name,t1.last_name) NOT IN (SELECT CONCAT(t2.first_name,t2.last_name) FROM table2 t2)
```

Comment: concat is going to give false matches. (i.e. "ab", "cd" and "a", "bcd")

Comment: so maybe add a separator in the middle, like "ab" + "/" + "cd"

Comment: You can avoid the false matches by using a separator that is guaranteed not to be used by either column, but the bigger issue is that your query requires a full table scan due to your use of WHERE CONCAT. Indexes on the first_name or last_name columns won't be useful for the query planner.

Answer (score -5):

You should probably use `NOT EXISTS` for multiple columns.

Comment: How? Your answer provides no details.

Comment: A brief why or how?