# sqlite: how can I add an autoincrementing id to an existing table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I would like to add an autoincrementing integer field called `uid` to an existing table `assoc`, but it doesn't look like I can do that unless it's a primary key.

I have fields `local_id` and `remote_id` which are the existing primary key pair, and I do that so that I can `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO assoc` so that I don't get duplicate primary keys, but if I have a pair of columns as a primary key, I can't seem to use them as an update ([see other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622353/how-to-update-in-sqlite-using-a-left-join-to-select-candidate-rows/4622371#4622371)).

Could anyone suggest how to restructure the table (and implement that restructuring using `ALTER TABLE`) so that I can get the behavior I need:

- a single autoincrementing key, so I can use that for `UPDATE`s
- a pair of fields `local_id` and `remote_id` so that the pair `(local_id, remote_id)` remains unique in the table

Comment: I just posted an answer in your other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you could drop the primary key on your existing columns, create the new primary key integer autoincrementing column, then create a UNIQUE index on the other two columns.

Comment: cool, that's a good alternative. Hey, if there's a builtin rowid, why would I ever want the autoincrementing primary key?

Comment: If I understand the docs correctly, if you declare INTEGER PRIMARY KEY it simply aliases the ROWID value.  If you explicitly declare INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT you get slightly different (safer) behavior.  Here's the man page: http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html.

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I don't need to -- there's a builtin `rowid` column.

Comment: It's not a good idea to rely on rowid to link to other tables as the  rowid can get reassigned to a new item if the first item is deleted