# sqlite: how to update data from one row to another in a join

Tags: sqlite, join

SQLite doesn't support updates with joins. (see [this closely related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622353/how-to-update-in-sqlite-using-a-left-join-to-select-candidate-rows))

Let's say I have a table `data` with these columns:

```
INTEGER id
TEXT foo
TEXT bar
TEXT baz
```

and I have another table `selection` with one column `INTEGER id`.

What I would like to do is given an integer id `srcID`, to copy the `foo` and `bar` values from the `data` row src to the `data` rows where the ids match the selection table.

In "standard" SQL (or at least the MySQL variant), this is something like

```
UPDATE data, selection, data as src
  SET data.foo = src.foo, data.bar = src.bar
  WHERE data.id = selection.id
  AND src.id = ?
```

(`?` = prepared statement value set to `srcID`)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Last time I used Oracle, I don't think it supported your syntax either.

I don't see how you could do that with a single SQL command in SQLite, but have you looked into using an UPDATE trigger on the data table?